# How to control the font size of html select boxes on iPhone

Tags: iphone, html

Regular HTML select boxes (such as, e.g. found [here](http://www.tizag.com/htmlT/htmlselect.php)), while being "chosen" are presented by the iPhone on a native widget that seems to totally ignore regular html font sizes and whatnot. It does some ellipsing when it goes too long, but the font is way too big for a list I want to present -- even on landscape, only about 35 characters can fit.

Is there any way to tell the iPhone to use a smaller font there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible. Use radio buttons instead.

Also, you can create custom select boxes. If created the good way, it works great. One small misstep and the UI is a disaster.

Comment: When the dropdown has hundreds of options, radio buttons are hardly a useable alternative. :/

Comment: @Martha hunderds of options would suck anyway.

Comment: Machine, and your point is? (This is about as useful as telling the driver stuck in the snow that rear-wheel-drive sucks, he should get a 4WD.)